# How would I reload custom views in a scroll view?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view that loads custom views (using a nib) from CoreData. They appear in a x by 2 grid that scrolls vertically. The problem I face is reloading the scroll view when I add or delete an item. I have tried redrawing the views once my data has been updated, but right now my solution is re-instantiating the view controller that holds my data from the very beginning of the navigation stack, thus redrawing the views as I need. The problem with this is that it creates extra views (UINavigationView) in the hierarchy, which is not a desired behavior.

How would I achieve the same result without creating extra views in the hierarchy?

This is my ViewController
[image: Home Screenshot]

Comment: Your use of view controllers to load multiple subviews of a scroll view simultaneously seems suspect. Have you considered using UICollectionView with a flow layout? It does automatically exactly what you seem to be describing. Or, if you really must use view controllers, how about a UIPageViewController? Of course I might not be understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: @matt, What do you mean by, it seems suspect? I have not considered a Collection View, but I will look into that. I added a picture just in case it helps one see what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the picture. It sure looks like a UICollectionView to me! I think you'd be a lot happier using that. As I say, it does a wonderful automatic job of dealing with insertion or deletion of a cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your image, I would suggest abandoning your entire architecture and just using a UICollectionView. The three red rectangles would then be UICollectionViewCells. UICollectionView does a wonderful automatic job of dealing with insertion or deletion of a cell; indeed, it even animates the change.